# Eloquent belongsToMany with pivot column as third identifier for sync

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two models as follows,

```
User {
    public function param()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Models\Param::class, 'param_user_map', 'user_id', 'param_id')
                ->withPivot('experience', 'param_extra');
    }
}

Params {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Models\User::class, 'param_user_map', 'param_id', 'user_id')
                ->withPivot('experience', 'param_extra');
    }
}
```

And my mapping table,

```
param_user_map
  -param_id
  -user_id
  -experience
  -param_extra
```

And data which I am working on is like,

```
user_id  param_id  experience  param_extra
51       2         3           param2_1
51       2         3           param2_2
51       3         3           param3_2
```

When I use Eloquent to sync this data only one of the first two is saved.

Is there any way I can sync data with [param_id,user_id,param_extra] as unique combination.

I tried with,

```
$table->unique(['param_id','user_id','param_extra']);
```

and

```
foreach ($data['param_collection'] as $param) {
    $params = [
        'experience' => $params['experience'],
        'param_extra' => $params['param_extra'],
    ];
    $user->param()->sync([$param['param_id'] => $params]);
}
```

Didn't work.

Any solution ?

Comment: This answer will probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27230803/3551175

Comment: I tried that, in my case I have to save two entries with same param_id and user_id with different pivot value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do what you want with `sync`. If you want to do more than just creating unique "User"-"Param" pairs with no extra attributes, you can use `attach`:

```
foreach ($data['param_collection'] as $param) {
    $user->param()->detach(); //if you want to clear previous params

    $user->param()->attach($param['param_id'], [
        'experience' => $param['experience'],
        'param_extra' => $param['param_extra']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I am already doing it with detach() and attach(), was wondering if there is a way to do it with sync(). Anyhow I checked the sync implementation and I cant override the sync() method. Thanks anyway.