# 3 models many-to-many sync in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 models with the relations many-to-many:

**Module**

```
public function permissionTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PermissionType::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('role_id');
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('permission_type_id');
}
```

**Role**

```
public function permissionTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PermissionType::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('module_id');
}

public function modules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('permission_type_id');
}
```

**PermissionType**

```
public function roles() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('module_id');
}

public function modules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class, 'permissions')->withPivot('role_id');
}
```

tables description:

**modules**

```
id
title
status
```

**roles**

```
id
title
```

**permission_types**

```
id
title
```

pivot table **permissions**

```
id
role_id
module_id
permission_type_id
```

My **synchronization** looks like:

```
//array of ids from request to synchronization 
$permissions = $request['permissions'];

//role by id from request
$role = Role::findOrFail((int)$roleId);

//module by id from request
$module = Module::findOrFail((int)$moduleId);

//synchronization
$pivotData = array_fill(0, count($permissions), ['role_id' => $role->id]);
$syncData  = array_combine($permissions, $pivotData);
$module->permissionTypes()->sync($syncData);
```

When trying to make the synchronization, have an error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'permissions' (SQL: select `permissions`.*, `permissions`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `permissions`.`permission_id` as `pivot_permission_id` from `permissions` inner join `permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `permissions`.`permission_id` where `permissions`.`role_id` = 1)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are trying to design a triple many to many that does not exists in Laravel. The solution, usually is to give the pivot table (in your case `permissions`) a Model (**Permission** in below code) for defining `hasManyThrough` relations.

If I understood well your table structure I will design the following relationships:

**Module**

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
}
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Role::class, Permission::class);
}
public function permissionTypes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PermissionType::class, Permission::class);
}
```

**Role**

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
}
public function permissionTypes()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(PermissionType::class, Permission::class);
}   
public function modules()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Module::class, Permission::class);
}
```

**PermissionType**

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
}
public function modules()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Module::class, Permission::class);
}
public function roles()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Role::class, Permission::class);
}
```

**Permission**

```
public function permissionType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PermissionType::class);
}
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
public function module()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
}
```

Tell me if it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Can You help with a working example, how to update each row of pivot table?

Comment: I found it -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230672/laravel-sync-how-to-sync-an-array-and-also-pass-additional-pivot-fields. Suppose, this is my case, but have an error above