# Update order in pivot table when using sync in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2, I have the following code:

```
    $thingIds = [];
    foreach ($this->things as $thing) {
        $thingIds[] = $thing->id;
    }
    $thong->things()->sync($thingIds);
    $thong->save();
```

Which seems to work for me, however in my pivot table I have an `order` column that isnt being updated/synced correctly.  The order is set to 1 for each item in the pivot table, however I want the order to be representative of the order of the ids in `$thingIds`.

Is this possible?

Is it possible to update an additional column in the pivot table using `->sync()`?

---

After the suggestion in the comments, I have also tried the following code:

```
    $thingIds = [];
    foreach ($this->things as $index => $thing) {
        $thingIds[$thing->id] = ['order' => $index];
    }
    $thong->things()->sync($thingIds);
    $thong->save();
```

And I have tried

```
    $thingIds = [];
    $order = [];
    foreach ($this->things as $index => $thing) {
        $thingIds[] = $thing->id;
        $order[] = ['order' => $index];
    }
    $thong->things()->sync(array_combine($thingIds, $order));
    $thong->save();
```

But neither of these is working (the order is still 1 for each item in the pivot table).  Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

---

If I do the attaching one at a time, like so:

```
    foreach ($this->things as $index => $thing) {
        $thong->things()->attach($thing, ['order' => $index]);
    }
```

The order comes out correctly in the pivot table.  How can I get the same effect but whilst still using `->sync()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, sync() - how to sync an array and also pass additional pivot fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230672/laravel-sync-how-to-sync-an-array-and-also-pass-additional-pivot-fields)

Comment: @Maraboc please see my edit

Comment: Try it like this : `foreach ($this->things as $index => $thing) {
        $thingIds[] = $thing->id;
        $order[] = ['order' => $index];
    }
    $thong->things()->sync(array_combine($thingIds, $order));` :)

Comment: @Maraboc thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately that didnt work either :( any other ideas?

Comment: Is there an error or any thing ?

Comment: no error, just all the order values are 1...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156019/discussion-between-maraboc-and-jimmery).