# use sync method for an array and also add extra pivot fields?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

**This is my input array**

```
"events" => array:2 [▼
"special-date" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "14-Nov-1979"
  1 => "18-Apr-1981"
  2 => "12-Nov-1978"
]
"event" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "3"
  2 => "4"
]
```

]

**This is my code**

```
$User->events()->sync($request->events['event'], ['event_date' => $request->events['special-date']]);
```

here, $user is an instance of the user model

**This is my user model realtion function**

```
 public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Event', 'user_events', 'user_id', 'event_id')->withPivot('event_date');
}
```

**and I got an error of event_date has no default value.**

**my table structure of a user_event table is**

**id,
user_id,
event_id,
event_date**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, sync() - how to sync an array and also pass additional pivot fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230672/laravel-sync-how-to-sync-an-array-and-also-pass-additional-pivot-fields)

Comment: Yes, but I can't get the desired solution, I got above error.

Comment: You are passing two arrays with data to the sync method, you have to pass it in one array. The accepted answer  in the linked question explains it.