# how to add extra data with sync method laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I have three tables:  products,  features,  and feature_product that third table has one extra column "value" that I want add value of each feature while syncing

so sync method is working without value but whenever I want to send value it gives me error

here is my code

```
  if($request->get('feature')){
      foreach($request->get('feature') as $featureName)
      {
          $feature = Feature::find($featureName);
          if($feature)
          {
            $featureIds[] = $feature->id;
          }
      }

      $product->features()->sync($featureIds);
    }
```

here is my error

> General error: 1364 Field 'value' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `feature_product` (`feature_id`, `product_id`) values (11, 99))

I konw this is because I did not send value for that , I want to know How can I do this

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: There's a section "_Syncing Associations_" in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27230672/4484016 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58647256/4484016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing pivot value in sync that why you're getting this error.

```
if($request->get('feature')){
    $featureIds = array();
    foreach($request->get('feature') as $featureName)
    {
      $feature = Feature::find($featureName);

      if($feature){
        $featureIds[$feature->id] = ['value'=>'yourvalue'];
      }
    }

    $product->features()->sync($featureIds);
}
```

Try to make this kinda array to sync.

```
$product->features()->sync( array( 
    1 => array( 'value' => 'xyz' ),
    2 => array( 'value' => 'abc' ),
    ...
));
```